# How do I create a passthrough query in access using a DSN-less connection?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010, dsn

I'm using DSN-less connections to my SQL Server in an Access database.  However, whenever I try to write a "Pass-Through" query and run it, a dialog box pops up asking for the DSN.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In SQL view, choose properties after you have selected passthrough query and insert an ODBC connect string. For example:

```
ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=Server\Instance;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Test
```

See also: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: Ahhh, under "ODBC Connect Str".  How easy, but so hard to find.  Thanks!

Comment: Will someone explain why this is the case? Shouldn't the Query pass through easily with the DSN-less connection?